# R: problems matching two vectors

Tags: r, match

I have one object called `lengthData`:

```
> class(lengthData)
[1] "numeric"
> length(lengthData)
[1] 19804
> head(lengthData)
XLOC_000001 XLOC_000002 XLOC_000003 XLOC_000004 XLOC_000005 XLOC_000006 
       2796        5223         733       11433        1628         414
```

And one called `DEgenes`:

```
> class(DEgenes)
[1] "integer"
> length(DEgenes)
[1] 19442
> head(DEgenes)
XLOC_000001 XLOC_000002 XLOC_000003 XLOC_000004 XLOC_000005 XLOC_000007 
          0           0           1           0           1           0
```

I need to make `lengthData` the same length as `DEgenes`, i.e. contain the same genes. I tried using:

```
DElength = lengthData[DEgenes]
```

But then the length of `DElength` is only 6124 which is the numer of genes with 1 in `DEgenes`.

Comment: That's because `DEgenes` is 1s and 0s, which get interpreted as `TRUE` and `FALSE`. You might try using `1:lengthData(DEgenes)` or `lengthData[names(lengthData) %in% names(DEgenes)]`. I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do though, so that code is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand, you want only the elements in `lengthData` which are also in `DEgenes`. So you could run:

```
lengthData[names(lengthData) %in% names(DEgenes)]
```